# Incorrect version of vmmom kernel module

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, vmware-workstation

I just installed the VMware Workstation Player virtual machine on my laptop running Ubuntu.  On the final step of installation, I get the error message "Version mismatch with vmmon module: expecting 360.0, got 309.0.
You have an incorrect version of the 'vmmon' kernel module" Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add more info about the version of vmware you are using, other software and libraries, the environment or anything else that could help figure out your version conflict.

Comment: The version of VMware is VMware Workstation 15 Player 15.0.0 build -10134415.  I just downloaded and installed VMware onto my computer for the first time and I tried to create a new VM using the Ubuntu 18.04 iso file.  I recently wiped the host computer, a Dell-E6420, and installed Ubuntu 18.04 as the OS.  Let me know if there is any other information which might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The below technique manually rewrites `vmmon` and is from a [vmware forum](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/456399) (and other places). This worked well for me for my Ubuntu 18.04 guest on a MacOS host.

- Quit Fusion.
- In terminal:

`sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/vmmon.kext`

`sudo cp -pR /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/kexts/vmmon.kext /System/Library/Extensions/`

`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/vmmon.kext`

`sudo kextutil /System/Library/Extensions/vmmon.kext`

VMWare should restart correctly with the new version.